# Prepend to lines of a program as they come in

Tags: bash

I'm running xinput test and trying to timestamp the data.

From another question, I'm using :

```
xinput test $KEYBOARD_ID | (echo -n $(date +"$date_format") && cat) > $LOGFILE_NAME
```

However, that dates the first line, not every line.

If I do a while loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
     echo -n $(date +"date_format") &&cat)
done < $(xinput test $KEYBOARD_ID)
```

The loop exits right away, since xinput test is yet to generate any text.

Process substitution fails as well, only dating the first line of the file.

```
while IFS= read -r line 
do
    (echo -n $(date +"$date_format") && cat) > $LOGFILE_NAME
done < <(xinput test $KEYBOARD_ID)
```

Writing to file and post-processing won't work, because I need the timestamp when each line was processed.

I feel like I'm making a small error, but I can't find it, any input?

Comment: I forgot to add that I tried that as well, it also only dates the beginning of the file.

Comment: I think you should change accepted answer to @user000001's solution.

Comment: Changed - didn't notice the date issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following GNU awk command is equivalent to @karakfa's answer, but launches fewer processes, so it could be faster if the device is generating a lot of events:

```
xinput test "$KEYBOARD_ID" | gawk '{print strftime(), $0}' > "$LOGFILE_NAME"
```

Comment: `gawk` to the rescue!

Comment: This appends the current time to each line as they arrive. The other answer does not.

Comment: @thatotherguy: You are correct, I tested the other answer again and it doesn't update with current time. Too bad I already upvoted it :)

Answer (score 2):

perhaps this will help...

```
$ seq 10 | xargs -n1 -I {} echo $(date) {}

Wed May 10 14:43:09 EDT 2017 1
Wed May 10 14:43:09 EDT 2017 2
Wed May 10 14:43:09 EDT 2017 3
Wed May 10 14:43:09 EDT 2017 4
Wed May 10 14:43:09 EDT 2017 5
Wed May 10 14:43:09 EDT 2017 6
Wed May 10 14:43:09 EDT 2017 7
Wed May 10 14:43:09 EDT 2017 8
Wed May 10 14:43:09 EDT 2017 9
Wed May 10 14:43:09 EDT 2017 10
```

Note that, as commented below, this time stamp won't be updated for each line, if you want to time stamp each new line the `gawk` solution by [user000001](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43900576/1435869)

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind explaining what the curly braces do?

Comment: first instance corresponds to the naming the placeholder and second instance the placeholder for replacing with the actual argument.  It can be any other string as well, but conventionally `{}` is used.

Comment: Understood - I figured it was something along those lines. Thanks again!

Comment: This writes the exact same timestamp for all lines, even when output is slow and lines arrive over time.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel like I'm making a small error, but I can't find it

Yep. It's the `cat`. It reads the rest of the input and puts it there. Instead, you should just write the current line, and append it to the file:

```
while IFS= read -r line 
do
    (echo "$(date +"$date_format") $line") >> $LOGFILE_NAME
done < <(xinput test $KEYBOARD_ID)
```

Which can more canonically be written as

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "$(date +"$date_format") $line"
done < <(xinput test $KEYBOARD_ID) > "$LOGFILE_NAME"
```

I would go for @user000001's shorter and more efficient solution though.